# Visual Studio Code: Select each occurrence of word (case sensitive)

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is used to select all the instances of word/selection, but is there a case sensitive version of this command?

Comment: Not sure if you're already aware but a little toolbar pops up and Code seems to remember selected options.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it earlier, i tried this with the search bar actually. If anyone reading didn't get it, try `ctrl` + `F` and then use `ctrl` + `shift` + `L`.

Comment: You can use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Cardinal90.multi-cursor-case-preserve) package that smartly 'preserves' case, so `userName` and `User` automatically become `customerName` and `Customer`. 

A true lifesaver.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Windows (or <kbd>⎇ Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on MacOS) you are toggling case sensitivity for:

1. Search <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
2. Select next occurrence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
3. Select all instances <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)

Answer (score 37):

For Mac <kbd>⎇ Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will toggle case sensitivity:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to 'preserve case' you can also use `Multiple cursor case preserve` as found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Cardinal90.multi-cursor-case-preserve):

[image: Replacing multiple rows at once]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

^ You can also select the "whole word" or case sensitivity in the upper right where the "search" input is usually displayed.

Comment: I downvoted you by mistake sorry... I'm unable to undo it :( great answer